# How could I send a message to a user that had note for my bot?

Tags: discord.js

I had set up the webhooks correctly for dblapi.js and I need help with sending a message to a user.

My code:

```js
dbl.webhook.on("vote", vote => {
     let { message } = require("discord.js");
     let voted = vote.user.id;
     voted.send("thanks for voting")
});
```

Will this work? If not, can you show me the proper way to do it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from the [DBL Api Docs](https://discordbots.org/api/docs#jslib):

> [image: DBL Docs]

So we first have to get the User Object and then send the dm. `vote.user.id` will not work as `vote.user` already is the ID.

Here is how it can and should be done.

```
dbl.webhook.on("vote", vote => {
     console.log('User with ID ' + vote.user + ' voted!');
     const user = client.users.get(vote.user); // This will get the User Object from the Client#users Collection
     if(user) { // This checks if the Bot knows who the User is.
         user.send('Thank you for voting!'); // DM the User "Thank you for voting!"
     }
});
```

Comment: More details please.

Comment: So I put your code in my index.js, but when I voted, it doesn't log in the console and didn't sent me a message

Comment: Was it ever working before? If not then it is not an issue with the Code, but rather with your network setup, in wich case I can only tell you make sure to PortForward, using dbl webhook is like hosting a website. For that you may get better support in DBL Discord Server at https://discordapp.com/invite/EYHTgJX

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work, got if from [here](https://discordbots.org/api/docs#jslib).

```js
dbl.webhook.on('vote', vote => {vote.user.send("thanks for voting")});
```